# Method not found error when consuming wcf service in android?

Tags: c#, android, wcf, wcf-configuration

[image]I am  developing wcf service.I am getting reponse fine in my windows phone app.but android people were getting error.they are getting html response.i.e,(my wcf debugging browser page).
 below is my code:

```
namespace SampleWcfproject
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "ISampleService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISampleService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/getdata/{uuid}", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string getdata(string uuid);

         [OperationContract]
        string getcities();
}}
```

my svc.cs page:

```
namespace SampleWcfproject
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "SampleService1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select SampleService1.svc or SampleService1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(
        RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class SampleService1 : ISampleService1
    {
        public  string getdata(string uuid)
        {
            try
            {


                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con2"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select CircleID, CircleName from Circle", con);
                con.Open();
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
                // DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                JavaScriptSerializer JSSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> DtRows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> newrow = null;

                //Code to loop each row in the datatable and add it to the dictionary object
                foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    newrow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        newrow.Add(col.ColumnName.Trim(), drow[col]);
                    }
                    DtRows.Add(newrow);
                }
                con.Close();
                var rowString = JSSerializer.Serialize(DtRows);

                //rowString = rowString.Trim('"');

              rowString =  rowString.Substring(1, rowString.Length - 2);

               return rowString;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                List<String> Parameters = new List<String>();
                Parameters.Add("getRechargeCircleList");

             //   SendErrorMail(ex.ToString(), "getRechargeCircleList", Parameters);
               // Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
               // Context.Response.Write(@" {""Status"":""false"",""Message"" : ""Oops! Something went Wrong""}");
               // return;
            }
            return "false";
        }
```

web.config page:

```
 <system.web>

    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="32768"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
     <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <!--
        The <authentication> section enables configuration 
        of the security authentication mode used by 
        ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
   <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
        The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
        of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
        during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
        it enables developers to configure html error pages 
        to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
         <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
    -->
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- 
      The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
      Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>

  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>

        <binding name="basicHttpBinding" allowCookies="true"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" 
                 maxBufferSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                 maxArrayLength="200000000"
                 maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
    <services>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="SampleWcfproject.Service1Behavior" name="SampleWcfproject.Service1">

        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SampleWcfproject.IService1">



        <!--<endpoint address="basic" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="SampleWcfproject.IService1">-->



          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>



          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>



      <!--<service behaviorConfiguration="SampleWcfproject.SampleService1Behavior" name="SampleWcfproject.SampleService1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SampleWcfproject.ISampleService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>-->




    </services>

    <behaviors>
       <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>

        <behavior name="SampleWcfproject.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>



        <!--<behavior name="SampleWcfproject.SampleService1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>-->





      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is the exception you get from the IIS?

Comment: You should post your android code

Comment: @UdiIdan actually i did not get any exception in iis.  I normally get data  whenever I consumed in my windows phone.but android people getting error. I don't know what happend.

Comment: You get an error about your endpoint, so your Android code is needed. As we know that the WCF is generally ok.

Comment: @UdiIdan ok i will tell you

Comment: @UdiIdan   any end point address required? in my web.config file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92517/discussion-between-anil-kumar-and-udi-idan).

Comment: @UdiIdan please check the below link this  is my andriod code.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183506/how-to-use-wcf-services-in-android-using-retrofit